Shopware 6 on HTTP (without SSL)
Is it possible to set Shopware 6 to work properly without SSL?
I have this error in the log, I suppose it is because it is running on HTTP:
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\InvalidKeyProvided: "It was not possible to parse your key, reason: * error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line * error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line * error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line" at InvalidKeyProvided.php line 13 {"exception":"[object] (Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\InvalidKeyProvided(code: 0): It was not possible to parse your key, reason:\n* error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line\n* error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line\n* error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line at /shopware/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/InvalidKeyProvided.php:13)"} []

I tried to find some solution, but without success. If someone has some experience with Shopware 6 or Symfony could help
